# Set ComboBox ViewModel Selected Index Default

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I'm trying to bind a ComboBox to a ViewModel and set it's default `SelectedIndex` to  `0` or the first item.

When I set the default `SelectedIndex` in the ViewModel it does not work.

Though it works with `SelectedItem`.

---

### XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboExample"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Example_Items}"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Example_SelectedIndex}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Example_SelectedItem}"

          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="0,0,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="105" 
          Height="22"/>
```

---

### ViewModel

Note: I only set one or the other.

```
public ViewModel()
{
    // ComboBox Defaults

    Example_SelectedIndex = 0; // does not work

    Example_SelectedItem = "item 1"; //works
}
```

**Item Source**

```
public List<string> _Example_Items = new List<string>()
{
    "item 1",
    "item 2",
    "item 3"
};
public List<string> Example_Items
{
    get { return _Example_Items; }
    set
    {
        _Example_Items = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Example_Items");
    }
}
```

**Selected Index**

Not Working

```
public int _Example_SelectedIndex { get; set; }

public int Example_SelectedIndex
{
    get { return _Example_SelectedIndex; }
    set
    {
        if (_Example_SelectedIndex == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _Example_SelectedIndex = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Example_SelectedIndex");
    }
}
```

**Selected Item**

Works

```
public string _Example_SelectedItem { get; set; }

public string Example_SelectedItem
{
    get { return _Example_SelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (_Example_SelectedItem == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _Example_SelectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Example_SelectedItem");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you set both properties (SelectedIndex and SelectedItem) in XAML?

Comment: @Babbillumpa no just one, I just showed for example.

Comment: Have you checked for binding errors in Output window?

Comment: @Babbillumpa I do not see any errors relating to this combobox.

Comment: You can only bind to properties. the first view model has fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Example_SelectedIndex on data load completion i.e. Example_Items.

```
   private _Example_Items;
   public List<string> Example_Items
    {
        get 
        { 
            if(_Example_Items == null)
            {
                loadExampleItems();
            }

            return _Example_Items; 
        }
        set
        {
            _Example_Items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Example_Items");
        }
    }
```

//In case, if you get the Data from the server this will be the asynchronous response method.

```
private void loadExampleItems()
{
     var examples = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "item 1",
                        "item 2",
                        "item 3"
                    };

     Example_Items = examples;
     Example_SelectedIndex = Example_Items.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: It can't convert Item `string` to Index `int` so I used `Example_SelectedItem = Example_Items.FirstOrDefault();` and it works. But why does it not work with `Example_SelectedIndex = 0` like in my code?

Comment: SelectedIndex will change based on the seletedItem in the collection. If you set the SelectedItem, it will also update the SelectedIndex, You should use the SelectedIndex as OneWay binding to know what is the index.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind to both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex`. It's one or another. This works just fine for me:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Example_SelectedIndex = 0; //unnecessary since the default value of an int is 0
    }

    private List<string> _Example_Items = new List<string>()
    {
        "item 1",
        "item 2",
        "item 3"
    };
    public List<string> Example_Items
    {
        get { return _Example_Items; }
        set { _Example_Items = value; }
    }

    private int _Example_SelectedIndex;
    public int Example_SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _Example_SelectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (_Example_SelectedIndex == value)
                return;

            _Example_SelectedIndex = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboExample"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Example_Items}"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Example_SelectedIndex}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="0,0,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="105" 
          Height="22"/>
```

By the way, `_Example_SelectedIndex` should be a private field and not a public property. `_Example_Items` should be private as well.

Comment: @MattMcManis: Did you try this?